# My website is hidden for using copyright content under DMCA complaint. How can i get it back?

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, dmca

My website is hidden for using copyright content under DMCA complaint. How can i get it back ? now it is showing "In response to a complaint that we received under the US Digital Millennium Copyright Act, we have removed 10 result(s) from this page. If you wish, you may read the DMCA complaint that caused the removal(s) at example.com."

Answer (score 2):

If your website was hidden (as you've stated), once you've removed all of the content from your website that resulted in the complaint, talk to your web hosting provider (GoDaddy, 1and1, etc).  They should have no problem reactivating your website once this is done.

If it was, in fact, your website listing that was removed, your best option may be to fill out this form, choose other, and let them know the content was removed or select a more appropriate option.

https://support.google.com/legal/contact/lr_counternotice?product=websearch&uraw=&hl=en

Comment: I think that this question is referring to being hidden in the Google search results.  I don't think talking to a hosting provider will be able to help with that at all.

Comment: Yeah, he probably should've been a bit more specific, but having read this again that does make a bit more sense.

Comment: Modified my answer for clarity.

Comment: @kavin Remisoski : The form you are referring I have checked that. There is a mention that " Please note: If the content on the page was infringing at the time the original removal request arrived, your counter-notice is not legally valid. Do not submit a counter-notice if there was illegal content, even if it's now been removed." so  I can not do anything now :(  I copied the text from a website and they made a complaint, after receiving a mail from google regarding this, I removed the content within a second.